# What is the intersection of algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (that is, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$) and $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

What is the intersection of algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (that is, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$) and $\mathbb{C}$?

I guess that is just $\mathbb{Q}$, but why?

Comment: The question is, what do you mean by "intersection"?  Literally, as sets, they probably don't intersect at all, though it depends on exactly how you construct them as sets.

Comment: "The" algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_p$ (in what?) is not the same as $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ if the latter means an algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ (the first is uncountable, the second countable). Also, to sepak of an intersection, the sets have to be contained in a common set. Which one is that and how do both sets lie in that one? (One can embed $\mathbb Q_p$ and its algebraic closure into $\mathbb C$, but not explicitly, such embeddings need the axiom of choice, which most probably kills any hope for an explicit answer even if we use those embeddings to give sense to the question.)

Comment: In other word, is element of  $\bar{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ is in C?

Comment: You might be interested to know that $\overline {\Bbb Q_p}$ is actually isomorphic to $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Maybe yes, thank you.How p-adic number can be seen as an element of $C$?

Comment: @Nekojiru it can't. At least not if by "seen" you mean an explicit map from $\mathbb Q_p\to\mathbb C$. Abstractly, either by the axiom of choice or by model theory or by other inexplicit tools, you can prove that there is a (discontinuous) map $\mathbb Q_p\to \mathbb C$. You can also prove that, again as abstract fields, $\overline{\mathbb Q}_p\cong\mathbb C$. That isomorphism is discontinous, impossible to explicitly construct, and completely unenlightening (although sometimes quite useful!).

Comment: Once you fix an isomorphism $\overline{\mathbb Q}_p\cong\mathbb C$, you can talk about the intersection of $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb Q_p$. But it depends on which of the uncountably many maps you chose, and there's absolutely no way of knowing which! As such, the question is pretty meaningless

Comment: @Mathmo123 If one fixes an isomorphism $\overline{\Bbb Q_p} \simeq \Bbb C$, then the intersection of $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb Q_p$ is simply $\Bbb Q_p$, right? ^_^

Comment: @WhatsUp true :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that in set theory, you cannot really take an intersection $X \cap Y$ of two sets $X$ and $Y$ unless you already assume that $X$ and $Y$ are subsets of a larger set $Z$.

The question "What is $\overline{\mathbb Q_p} \cap \mathbb C$?" does not really make sense as the sets $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$ and $\mathbb C$ are not canonically contained in a larger set $Z$.

There are several, inequivalent definitions of both $\mathbb C$ and $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$ and depending on which definition you use, your question will have different answers.  In the various ways you could define these sets, you could correctly say that the answer to your question is $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$, or $\mathbb Q$, or the empty set!

So your question isn't really meaningful.  Note, however, that there are (infinitely many) field isomorphisms $\mathbb C \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb Q_p}$.  This is due to a standard result about transcendence bases that can be found in any graduate algebra textbook.

Answer (score 1):

For any field $K$ containing both $E\cong \overline{\Bbb{Q}_p}$ and $F\cong \Bbb{C}$ you'll have that $E\cap F$ (which makes sense, in contrary to your question) contains $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$.

For the remaining part it depends on $K$ and the embeddings $\overline{\Bbb{Q}_p},\Bbb{C}\to K$.

- Taking an isomorphism (given by the axiom of choice) $\overline{\Bbb{Q}_p}\to\Bbb{C}$ you'll have $E=F=K$,
- taking $K=Frac(\overline{\Bbb{Q}_p}\otimes_{\overline{\Bbb{Q}}} \Bbb{C})$ you'll have $E\cap F=\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$.

  (the tensor product is a bit sloppy, we need to fix an embedding $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}\to \overline{\Bbb{Q}_p},\overline{\Bbb{Q}}\to \Bbb{C}$ first, but the resulting field and $E\cap F$ doesn't depend on it)
- Can you construct the intermediate cases?

Comment: Is it obvious that $\overline{\mathbb Q}_p\otimes_{\overline{\mathbb Q}}\mathbb C$ is a domain?

Comment: @Mathmo123 Do you mean "obvious" or "provable in ten words"?

Comment: I guess the latter?

Comment: So I guess we want to avoid the axiom of choice. If it fails to be a domain then it will be provable with finitely many $\otimes$ rules that $(\sum_j a_j\otimes b_j)(\sum_j c_j\otimes d_j)=0$, and those rules are the same as in a finitely generated algebra $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}[d_j]\otimes_\overline{\Bbb{Q}} \overline{\Bbb{Q}}[e_j]$ containing all the coefficients appearing in the proof, which is provable to be a domain because $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}[e_j]\cong \overline{\Bbb{Q}}[X_j]/I$ for some ideal which stays prime in $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}[d_j,X_j]$. Does it make sense?